# UITableView - increasing number of items after initial load

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, crash

in my app I ran into a problem. I have designed a UITableView with 3 sections. Each section has static cells, section one has one cell, section two has five cells and...section 3 initially has zero cells, but can have n cells approx. 10 seconds later.

Whenever I load the data and after the data has been loaded and I call self.tableView.reloadData(), my app crashes because of a NSRangeException.

The exception is thrown in cellForRow atIndex:

I did not implement this method, I do all the adjustments in willDisplayRow.

I return the number of rows like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    if section == 0
    {
        return 1
    }
    else if section == 1
    {
        return 5
    }
    else if section == 2
    {
        return self.data.count
    }

    return 0
}
```

At this moment, the data array does not contain any objects. How can I add more cells later on?

Comment: Show where you call `self.tableView.reloadData()`.

Comment: That is not important, I have loaded new data and added the data to my array. The problem is, that I can not create a new cell "on the fly".

I create new cells using this code:
        else
        {
            tableView.register(ReviewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reviewCell")
            let reviewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reviewCell", for: indexPath)
            return reviewCell
        }

Unfortunately, all the outlets are nil (although they were connected to the controls using IB).

Comment: I understand this as a completely different issue than the one described in your question, so to me it is not clear what the actual question is. Maybe edit your question.